# How I can upload files in my userContent of jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm new in Jenkins, I want to upload a file from my local disk or from a Github repository in my userContent and be able to use it in a dsl job, so that it reads that file and can create 2 jobs. I have the code to create the 2 jobs but the problem is that I need to do it from a .groovy, .sh or whatever file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it! In the folder jenkins_home/userContent/ from my computer.